# Expression Programming

Tags: math, expression, formula, equation, simplify

I have built a full working calculator that evaluates any expression and graphs it. I have also built a **Symbolic Differentiator** that correctly differentiates the formula w.r.t. x but im a bit lost for how to simplify any generic equation programmatically because at the minute the answers are coming out with many multiples of ones. I realise a*1 is easily simplified but i need an all round simplifier to cover any situation.

Comment: The freeest (license-wise) way to do it IMHO, is to use [sympy](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki) to do the simplifications for you.

Comment: No, I need to do it myself, it's for an iOS app anyway so i don't think i can implement that library there. I have got simple equations to be simplified where it looks at each 'letter' like X and simplifies by looking at the powers of X for each of the rest of the expressions within it but it won't work with brackets or other functions.

Comment: The point is that you're looking for a computer algebra system (CAS), c++ computer algebra system turned up [SymbolicC++](http://issc.uj.ac.za/symbolic/symbolic.html) though it has a GPL license, which might not suit your needs. If you insist on doing it from scratch, I think that's more of a math problem than a programming one, and that's out of scope of Stackoveflow. You could also consider doing the simplification on a server, then you don't have to work around the arbitrary limitations of an evil corporation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd think of simplification as a form of normalization. Probably the first thing you might want to implement is simplification of polynomials:

- Compute any subexpressions which contain no variables at all
- Define an order for your variables, unless *x* is the only valid variable for you
- Order terms in monomials according to their variables
- Based on this order of variables, define an order for monomials, which takes variables and their degrees into account
- Order terms for a polynomial according to their monomials
- Identify duplicate monomials and combine their coefficient
- Remove all monomials which turn out to be zero

If you want to also simplify expressions containing functions, things can become arbitrary complex. In general, I'd try to define some way to measure the simplicity of a term, i.e. given two terms, decide which of the two is simpler. Then you can think of rules and check whether you can guarantee that they will only ever make your terms simpler. You might also want to check for termination (i.e. there is no way your terms can become ever simpler for an infinite number of steps) and confluence (i.e. when there are two possible simplifications, it won't matter which one you do next, as the end result will be the same).

You might want to read some literature on [term rewriting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewriting#Term_rewriting_systems), [rewrite systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewriting) and related topics.

Comment: Thanks for your input, what you have said is pretty much what I needed and it is matching my own development of the solution so far, the functions are indeed proving to be difficult.